# Can a single user have multiple crontab files?

Tags: linux, cron, non-root-user

Suppose I am creating two crontab files.

1. `/tmp/my-crontab`
2. `/root/my-alternate-crontab`

Each crontab file is sheduled to run diffrent scripts.

When I start the cronjob the first is replaced with the older one.

```
crontab -u smarak /tmp/my-crontab
crontab -u smarak /root/my-alternate-crontab
```

Is the above possible for a single user ?

Comment: Why do not have all the commands in one cron? Or use at for single runs?

Comment: Hi Romeo, Thanks for the quick response. Yes it is fine to take the commands in a single file. But just wanted to know why multiple crontab files for a single user is  not possible.

Answer (score 9):

Two ways to work around having a single crontab.

Put your crontab entries in files in some directory, like `~/crontab.d/thisandthat.cron`, then commit any changes from those to the system crontab with:

```
cat ~/crontab.d/*.cron | crontab -
```

The extension `.cron` is to avoid accidentally including backup files from editors. Note that since all the files are concatenated together, any variables set in the files will also apply to files that come later.

You could also do something similar to how `/etc/cron.hourly` and friends are implemented in Debian. The main `/etc/crontab` contains rules like this:

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

You could arrange for a single crontab entry to run multiple programs. Debian's `run-parts dir` is similar to `for f in dir/* ; do "$f" ; done` except that it skips odd filenames, again to avoid running backup files created by editors etc.

Comment: What does the `-` in `cat ~/crontab.d/*.cron | crontab -` do?

Comment: @Tian, it's a common notation to tell the program to read stdin instead of a named file: [_"The first form of this command is used to install a new crontab from some named file or standard input if the pseudo-filename `-` is given."_](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/cron/crontab.1.en.html).

Answer (score 3):

No.  Each user has one crontab. Why? Because the crontab is the "table" ("tab") of all cron jobs associated with a single user.

If you want to run multiple things with `cron`, just add multiple lines in your crontab.

If you have multiple files with cron job specifications, just concatenate them:

```
cat crontab1 crontab2 crontab3 >my-crontab
crontab my-crontab
```

Comment: It's common that root can have multiple crontab files under `/etc/cron.d/`. It's useful if you have a bundle of crontab entries that you want to maintain across multiple servers, and you don't know what changes might be made to the regular crontab.

Answer (score 1):

You could just read the actual entry and append the new one right after.
 
Once you have this one running:

```
crontab -u smarak /tmp/my-crontab
```

Ideally you could do something like:

> crontab -u smarak <(cat /root/my-alternate-crontab) <(crontab -l)

But it seems that crontab does not accept the form above so here the work-around:

```
cat /root/my-alternate-crontab <(crontab -l)| crontab -u smarak -
```

This works for me. 
Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks great! Though this solution is not idempotent (if you apply multiple times you won't get same result since `/root/my-alternate-crontab` will appear multiple times)